# Have you been washing your hair in the sink?

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect-progressive

I find some hair in the sink.

Can I ask "Have you been washing your hair in the sink?" without being angry or disapproving?

I am just asking about the activity that leads to the hair in the sink.

Comment: The tone you ask this question will matter much more than the words.  Any way to make this more polite or gentle will require context.

Comment: @ LawrenceC I am asking if my husband has been washing his hair in the sink, because there is hair in the sink. I want to know how it got there without being judgemental.

Answer (score 2):

You could say, "Just wondering..." or "Just curious..." before you begin your interrogation. Or: "Not that I care..." Or: "Not that I mind..." I suggest smiling, too, unless it's fake -- in which case it may have the opposite effect of what you intended. But first you might want to ask yourself why you want to talk to someone about their bathroom habits.

Comment: My question is if the present perfect continuous is the appropriate tense to use when you find evidence of a past action.

Comment: Well, I don't think tense has any bearing on whether you sound "angry or disapproving." The tense you used seemed correct to me, if that's all you're looking for.

Comment: Would "have you washed your hair in the sink" or "did you wash your hair in the sink" be okay in this context?

Comment: The former is asking if they have washed their hair one or more times in the sink. The latter implies that you're asking if they did it just once. Either is OK to ask. Neither suggests that you're angry or upset per se. If you're wondering if they do it as part of their regular routine, then the former is better. But in casual English, either could be used.

Comment: I don't mean" have you ever washed your hair in the sink".In this case where there is clearly evidence of hair washing, would "have you washed your hair in the sink", meaning recently, or "did you wash your hair in the sink" be appropriate?

Comment: OK, I would say: `Have you been washing your hair in the sink?`